# Search a Stateflow Chart or Transition by ID

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I have the following warning in Stateflow with IDs of a Chart and a Transition.

> Warning: Chart #404 has an unconditional transition #383 
>   that shadows the following transitions: #381 . 
>   You can also configure the diagnostic by clicking here.

Is there a way find this Chart #404 or this Transition #383? Maybe a command similar to `hilite_system`? I tried with the Find window but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: You should just be able to click on #404, #383 or #381 to take you to the right part of the model.

Comment: It's not clickable in the command window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @am304, there should be a hyperlink (at least in the error/warning dialog that appears, if not the command line), but failing that, you can use the Stateflow API:

```
>> rt = sfroot;  % Get the chart root
>> t = rt.find('-isa','Stateflow.Transition','Id',383); % Get the transition
>> t.view  % view the transition
```

For more info see the [API Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/programmatic-manipulation.html).